# How to pass as parameter a function with two parameter in C?

Tags: c, function, parameters

I want to pass a function a parameter that is a function with two parameters inside, and I can't find how to do it anywhere.

I'm trying this code but can't make the func2 use func1 properly.

```
typedef int (*visitFunc) (int n1, int n2);

int func1(int num1, int num2) {
  return num1 + num2;
}

int func2(int num1, int num2, visitFunc func (int n1, int n2) {
  return func(num1, num2);
}

int main() {

  int x = 2;
  int y = 5;
  int z = func2(x, y, func1);
  printf("%d\n", z);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working", *specifically*?

Comment: `int func2(int num1, int num2, visitFunc func)` visitFunc is the type that you have defined that includes the specification of number and types of parameters. func is the parameter name.

Comment: You also don't need to name the parameters in the function `typedef`.

Comment: @ScottHunter I mean that I can't make to use the function passed as a parameter to work inside the function (func2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function pointers without using `typedef`:

```c
int func2(int num1, int num2, int(*func) (int n1, int n2)) {
  return func(num1, num2);
}
```

However, it does look 'cleaner' when using `typedef`. In order for your code to work, you need to do what was already suggested in other comments/answers, which is to use `visitFunc func` as your function parameter:

```c
int func2(int num1, int num2, visitFunc func) {
  return func(num1, num2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `visitFunc func`.

```
//int func2(int num1, int num2, visitFunc func (int n1, int n2) {
int func2(int num1, int num2, visitFunc func) {
```

Also

Add `#include <stdio.h>`.